# VSCode Extension Databricks-Connect - Use SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-vscode-extension

I am using the Databricks VSCode extension for development in an IDE. The basic functionalities are all working well. I connected to an Azure Databricks workspace with Unity Catalog enabled, selected an active cluster (DBR 13.2) and configured the sync destination. I am able to execute code.
Now I want to use Databricks Connect "V2" to run my code locally.

I have the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Only remote Spark sessions using Databricks Connect are supported. Could not find connection parameters to start a Spark remote session.
```

Am I missing something? I did my authentication once with the AZ CLI, once with a PAT. I also tried it on DBR 13.2 and 13.3, but all options failed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured cluster in the VS Code as well?

Comment: @AlexOtt What do you mean with configured exactly? In the VSCode extension? I connected to a cluster in a UC-enabled workspace, DBR 13.2 and 13.3

Comment: Yes, in the extension...

Comment: @AlexOtt so yes, that one is configured...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that issue was fixed in the extension [version 1.1.1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=databricks.databricks) by exporting the `SPARK_REMOTE` environment variables that is needed for `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` to work.

But please note that it will work only if you configure profile-based authentication, not for `azure-cli` or OAuth authentication - for them to work you need to instantiate the `DatabricksSession` instance that could be imported with `from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that get's this error and does not wish to execute code using databricks.connect you have to completely uninstall the extension and package. I also recommend pip purge cache. Then you can reinstall the package and it should stop trying to use databricks.connect.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just had to run `pip uninstall databricks-connect` and that did the trick for me.